# Cannot access server by url

Tags: networking, server, dns, nginx

I setup an ubuntu server with nginx. hostname tleis.nl. I can access the url locally www.tleis.nl. 
From outside the server I can ping the server tleis.nl. I can also access the nginx website via its ip 192.168.x.y. But when I try to access www.tleis.nl. It fails.
I have the port forwarding setting on my router to forward public ip access to my local server's ip 192.168.x.y.
What could the issue be?

Comment: Your ISP might be blocking the port

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be an issue with the Port forwarding setting on the router. The Setting was lost after I configured it the first time!
Problem solved